# Why does this not work string a = "\u" + "30A0";?

Tags: java, string, unicode

Why does this work...

```
System.out.println("\u30A3");      output  ->   ィ
```

when this does not work?

```
System.out.println("\u" + "30A0");       output  ->  invalid unicode
```

Any ideas on how else i can do it?

That's because I have this code below, to automatically generate Katakana Unicode number so I can quickly grab any character from the Katakana language, but it seems not to work anyway.

```
ArrayList<String> symbols = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        if (k < 10) {
            symbols.add("\u30" + (char) (i + 65) + k);
        } else {
            symbols.add("\u30" + (char) (i + 65) + (char) (k - 10 + 65));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the same reason `"\" + "n"` doesn't work to create a newline.

Comment: By the way, when you ask "any ideas on how else I can do it" ... do _what_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a method that could be used, check it out:

```
public class Txt {

    private ArrayList<String> katakana = new ArrayList<>();

    public Txt() {
        for (int i = 0x30A0; i <= 0x30FF; i++) {
            katakana.add(String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i)));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getKatakana() {
        return new ArrayList<>(katakana);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This does not work because the processing of `\u` escape sequences [is done very early during the compilation process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.2). This means that you cannot concatenate bits of escape sequences as you are attempting to do in the second example.

To convert an integer code point (e.g. `0x30A0`) to a `char`, you could use [Character.toChars()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-).

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        if (k < 10) {
            symbols.add("\u30" + (char) (i + 65) + k);
        } else {
            symbols.add("\u30" + (char) (i + 65) + (char) (k - 10 + 65));
        }
    }
}
```

To create a Unicode character whose value is computed by your program, all you really need to do is compute the code point and then cast it to a `(char)`, as long as it's in the range `0` to `FFFF`.  (Code points `U+10000` and higher will need something different, I think `new String(new int[]{codePoint}, 0, 1)`.)  In your example, you're trying to compute `0x3000 + [16 times some letter value A-F] + [some digit or letter value]`, so

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
        char charValue = (char) (0x3000 + ((10 + i) << 4) + k);
        symbols.add(Character.toString(charValue));
    }
}
```

`(10 + i) << 4` gives you `00a0`, `00b0`, ..., which I think is what you want.

P.S. You don't even need a double loop.  Just one integer variable that goes from `0x00a0` to `0x00ff` will give you what I think you need.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of the way strings are handled by the compiler. When a string *literal* (that is, `"` + text + `"` in your source code) contains the magic sequence `\u`, you are telling the compiler *I want to have a Unicode character here. The next few (hexadecimal) numbers that follow define which one.*

But now you've ripped it apart: When the compiler sees the string literal `"\u"` it sees the `\u` and then wants some numbers *within the same literal*. But there aren't any. That's why you get the error message.